# How to find if the app crashed? on relaunch ? in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, crash

Say for example If I am in ViewController A - In that time App crashes for some reason.After that whenever user relaunch the App I have to show the ViewController A.

Thanks in Advance .!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app crashes, you can't restore your previous state.
There is only one solution as @PaulProgrammer explains , save the state of the application in a file for each new ViewController and read this file every each start / restart.

So you can write to a file or use NSUserDefault, there are several tutorial on restoration : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Write a file in the documents area that has the current state of the application (view controller, and any required context).  Each time the view changes, update the state file.  When the program launches, read the state file and restore the application state appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

[PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org) is your one stop solution. You can download the code from [here](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter).

Basically, this framework allow you to capture the crashes and save in file system.

On next app launch it allows you to get the pending crash reports using `loadPendingCrashReportDataAndReturnError:` method. You can make a server call and upload it on your server.

Once uploaded you can purge the pending crash reports by calling `purgePendingCrashReport` method.

Good Luck!